# Open poll results in popup / overlay

Tags: 7, polls

I'm using the Poll module in Drupal core (also using [Poll blocks](https://www.drupal.org/project/poll_blocks) and [Ajax poll](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_poll)).

As designed, when I vote I'm taken to the results page, but I'm wondering if it's possible to display the results as a popup on the front page, where the poll block is.

I searched a bit and I know something similar can be done with [lightbox2](https://www.drupal.org/project/lightbox2), [colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox), [colorbox node](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox_node), etc., but these solutions require that I assign a class or rel attribute to an anchor tag, and then open whatever URL I enter as a popup. However, the poll calls the results page on clicking the submit button. Is there a way I can change this to accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 1):

Please check answer. I think this may help you toy solve your problem.

**[ANSWER LINK](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/130184/drupal-popup-module-is-not-working-in-custom-front-page/130185#130185)**